# WPF PrintDialog.PrintVisual is not working on window 7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using `PrintVisual` to print a control; however, on Windows 7 the dialog appears but does not print anything. 
On Windows 8 it shows an error. 
Only works on Windows 10.

Here are my code:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog(); 
printDialog.PrintVisual(gridReport, "Report");
```

I saw this article but don't have any answer so I create a new question here hope that get the answer. 
[Previous question I found but no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298578/printvisual-is-not-working-on-windows-7).

Comment: Hope some one could help me.

Comment: I took this code and it is working on Window 7. Could you tell me the .net version you are using

Comment: I'm using framework 4.6. print to real printer.

Comment: I still need help. please any one get the answer?

Comment: @SatishPai could you help me

Comment: I don't have printer with me, But let me check what I can do.. @Clemens Could you please help him.